# consume restful web service

Tags: wcf

I would like to consume a third-party restful web service which exposes methods for GET requests. GET request are to be performed within a windows service + Timer and they all return JSON.

I would like, if possible, use WCF libraries for the de-serialization of JSON -> POCO whilst implementing forward-compatibility. The latter is implemented, as far as I understand, via DataContracts which implement IExtensibleDataObject. Can I use this approach to consume 3rd party restful (JSON) web services?

Any feedback appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to use the WCF client-side libraries to consume the third party service. The WCF client-side libraries were designed to use a defined service contract, either from a WSDL document or from an assembly with a `ServiceContract` class and related `OperationContract` and `DataContract` marked methods & classes. You can use the client-side libraries to consume JSON but you'd almost would have to "re-create" the third party service as a soap based service to produce the WSDL or write `ServiceContract` assembly for the service contract.

Look at this [short CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec) to see how to create a WCF JSON outputing *service* and how to configure the [WebHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.aspx) in WCF.

As to using the `IExtensibleDatObject` with JSON, this [other CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33063/Consuming-JSON-data-in-NET-with-WCF) has some good infomation but I don't think its applicable to your scenario since you would have to control the third party service contract.

Comment: Yeah I thought so (i.e. that I would have to recreate the ServiceContract to 'fake' the 3rd pary API. Not sure whether that's good practice/worth it?!

Comment: I guess it would be better to use something like: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: That's a better option or if you just need to focus on the JSON, look at [JSON.NET library](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx). It is used by Microsoft in place of the .NET JSON library for the ASP.NET Web API framework.

Comment: If I use RestSharp how do I ensure forward-compatibility? If the service adds an additional field to a JSON DTO is the only way to figure this out when my client breaks during de-serialization? Would it actually fail? Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

In IService1.cs page :-

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "Json/{id}")]
string myfun(string id);
```

In Service1.cs page:-

```
public string myfun(string id)
{
    string ConnectString = "server=localhost;database=test_local;integrated security=SSPI";
    string QueryString = "select * from tbl_af_register where id=" + id;

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(QueryString, myConnection);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "TestName");
    string i = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();

    return "your name is " + i;
}
```

In Web.Config File :-

In -> 'system.serviceModel' section

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService2.Service1">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService2.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
```

In 'behaviors' section of web.config:-

```
   <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
              <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
```

Note:- this name "web" should be same as -> behaviorConfiguration="web"